# What is the use of [0:5] and neigh (written in next line after assigning neigh)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, knn

The use of df.head() is to return first five rows the why [0:5] is used in the code and what is the use of X[0:5] written after 'preprocessing' line? And in KNeighbourClassifier after fitting 'neigh' why another single 'neigh' is used in the very next line? Please help, Thank You.

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import NullFormatter
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
from sklearn import preprocessing

    
df = pd.read_csv('https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net/cf-courses-data/CognitiveClass/ML0101ENv3/labs/teleCust1000t.csv')
df.head()

df['custcat'].value_counts()

df.hist(column='income', bins=50)

df.columns

X = df[['region', 'tenure','age', 'marital', 'address', 'income', 'ed', 'employ','retire', 'gender', 'reside']] .values  #.astype(float)
X[0:5]

y = df['custcat'].values
y[0:5]

X = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X).transform(X.astype(float))
X[0:5]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=4)
print ('Train set:', X_train.shape,  y_train.shape)
print ('Test set:', X_test.shape,  y_test.shape)

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

k = 4
#Train Model and Predict  
neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = k).fit(X_train,y_train)
neigh

yhat = neigh.predict(X_test)
yhat[0:5]

from sklearn import metrics
print("Train set Accuracy: ", metrics.accuracy_score(y_train, neigh.predict(X_train)))
print("Test set Accuracy: ", metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, yhat))
```

http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Downloads/ML0101EN-Clas-K-Nearest-neighbors-CustCat-py-v1.ipynb

Comment: There are lots of seemingly useless expression statements in this code. I suspect you are intended to run this line by line in an interactive session, so that you execute `yhat = neigh.predict(X_test)` to set the value of `yhat`, then execute `yhat[0:5]` to get a feel for what the `predict` method returned before proceeding to the following code that uses `yhat`.

Comment: Links to `localhost` won't help anyone.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't know. Is there anyway to upload that file?

Answer (score 0):

Step 3 of CRISP-DM is "Explore and clean your data". During this step you need to have a look at the data in order to judge about its quality. So you need some visible output after each step.

This code is used in a [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/) notebook. Jupyter notebooks will display the result of an expression. It acts like a `print()`, but smarter, so it will display images, tables etc.

However, it will only generate that output it it's the last line of a cell. Copying and pasting all code into a single cell will give you less output and it'll be harder to follow the analysis, because you don't see all the steps in between.

Here's a short example of what `df.head()` might output

[image: Output of Jupyter notebook]

Similarly, other seemingless useless statements will generate output:

[image: Other output]

From the comments:

> Would you please answer why they used first 3 [0:5], more importantly 3rd [0:5]? And why 'neigh' is used in "KNeighbourClassifier" part after the line "neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = k).fit(X_train,y_train)"?

`X[0:5]` will display the first 5 values of *X*. `Y[0:5]` will display the first 5 values of *Y*. And `neigh` will display whatever *neigh* is.

> And last one please. What does bins=50 mean?

It tells [`hist()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html) to create 50 bars in the diagram instead of 10. That way you can better judge about the distribution of values.

The nice thing about a Jupyter notebook (which you dson't seem to have discovered yet) is that you can easily change the statements and immediately get new output. Get a fresh Jupyter notebook, type one line of code. Press Ctrl+Enter, then do the same for the next line. You'll see what it does.

Comment: Would you please answer why they used first 3 [0:5], more importantly 3rd [0:5]? And why 'neigh' is used in "KNeighbourClassifier" part after the line "neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = k).fit(X_train,y_train)"?

Comment: `X[0:5]` will display the first 5 values of *X*. `Y[0:5]` will display the first 5 values of *Y*. And `neigh` will display whatever *neigh* is.

Comment: And last one please. What does bins=50 mean?

Comment: It tells hist() to create 50 bars in the diagram instead of 10.

Comment: If the solution worked for you, you can lick the checkmark on this answer. That way others will know that this question has an answer.